# Getting started with google appengine (python2.7) on UBUNTU

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu-12.04

I am following the tutorial, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld. I use Ubuntu 12.04

I prepared the helloworld example and then I got this message:

```
mark@einstein:~/Desktop$ google_appengine/dev_appserver.py ~/googleapps/helloworld/
WARNING  2013-02-13 15:58:32,107 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
INFO     2013-02-13 15:58:32,172 appcfg.py:586] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-02-13 15:58:34,369 appcfg.py:604] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2013-02-13 15:58:34,369 dev_appserver.py:3571] The datastore file stub is deprecated, and
will stop being the default in a future release.
Append the --use_sqlite flag to use the new SQLite stub.

You can port your existing data using the --port_sqlite_data flag or
purge your previous test data with --clear_datastore.

WARNING  2013-02-13 15:58:34,370 datastore_file_stub.py:518] Could not read datastore data from /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore
WARNING  2013-02-13 15:58:34,370 simple_search_stub.py:954] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/dev_appserver.searchindexes
INFO     2013-02-13 15:58:34,397 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:655] Running application dev~helloworld on port 8080: http://<<lch>>:8080
INFO     2013-02-13 15:58:34,397 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:657] Admin console is available at: http://<<lch>>:8080/_ah/admin
```

What should I do to get it working?

Comment: those warnings are "normal". Can you reach it on localhost:8080

Comment: That was it, I just realised my 'problem' was at a really basic level: I didn't realize I could see the output at http://<<lch>>:8080 in my browser  (<<lch>> stands for an illegal word on this forum: 'l0calh0st') I hope this helps someone else with very early starting up problems ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL (if not already)

and then Python MySQLdb
http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

see instructions here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.3/

as Paul C notes in a comment, the warnings are normal, the SDK is working fine, you just can't use the 'Google Cloud SQL' APIs without MySQL up and running

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have installed mysql-pythondb now. sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb.

Comment: did it get rid of the warnings?

Comment: Hi Anentropic, sorry for the late reaction, I just saw your question. The first warning disappeared (rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.) Otherwise it seems to be working alright.